# Hoffman and Kunze, linear algebra exercise

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c&d\end{bmatrix} , X =\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix}$

> Show that if $ad-bc=0$ and some entry of $A$ is different from $0,$ then there is a solution $(x_1^0,x_2^0)$ of the system $AX = 0$ such that $(x_1,x_2)$ is a solution if and only if there is a scalar y such that $x_1=yx_1^0,x_2=yx_2^0$.

My attempt :

One of the entry is non-zero; let it be $a.$ Trying to row reduce $A,$ we get
$$\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c&d\end{bmatrix} \to \begin{bmatrix}1 & b/a\\c&d\end{bmatrix} \to \begin{bmatrix}1 & b/a\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Let $$B=\begin{bmatrix}1 & b/a\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Since $AX=0$ and $BX=0$ have same solutions where $X=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix},$

thus, $x_1=(-b/a)x_2.$

Thus there is a solution $(x_1^0,x_2^0)=(-b,a).$ It is easy to verify that any multiple of this is also a solution.
But I have not been able to prove the forward direction i.e given any solution $(x_1,x_2)$ there is a scalar $y$ such that $x_1=yx_1^0,x_2=yx_2^0$.

P. S: I am reading Hoffman and Kunze and so far i have not reached linear independent sets, concept of basis etc. Only thing so far discussed is that row equivalent systems have same solutions and row reduction.

EDIT: I think the other direction can be done as follows:

suppose $(x_1,x_2)$ is a solution and $(x_1,x_2)\ne k(-b,a).$ then we would have $BX=0$ as $x_1+(b/a)x_2 \ne -bk + (b/a)ak=0,$ which is a contradiction.

Would this do?

Comment: *"if $ad-bc=0$ and some entry of $A$ is different from $0,$ then there is **a solution** $(x_1^0,x_2^0)$ such that..."* a solution *of what*, exactly?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thanks! I have edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your forward direction: from row-reduction, you know that since $X = (x_1,x_2)$ is a solution to $AX = 0$, it follows that
$$
\pmatrix{1 & \frac ba\\0&0}X = 0 \implies x_1 + \frac ba x_2 = 0 \implies\\ 
b = x_1 = 0, \quad \text{or } \quad \frac{x_1}{(-b)} = \frac{x_2}{(a)}
$$
In either case: let $y = x_2/a$.  By the above, note that $(x_1,x_2) = y(x_1^0,x_2^0)$, as desired.

Comment: wait..isn't it $x_1+(b/a)x_2?$

Comment: Yes. Fixed it.${}{}{}{}{}{}$